# How to add Azure AD group to SharePoint programmatically using c#

Tags: azure-active-directory, sharepoint-online

How can I add a Azure AD group to a SharePoint Online site collection administrators through a console application.

Answer (score 2):

My sample tested code, you may try it. TestSecurityGroup is an Azure AD security group.

```
Web web = clientContext.Web;
                var SPGroup = web.SiteGroups.GetById(7);
                User group = clientContext.Web.EnsureUser("TestSecurityGroup");
                clientContext.Load(group);
                User addUser=SPGroup.Users.AddUser(group);
                clientContext.Load(addUser);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: What is 7 in GetById ?? I need to add the group to Site Collection Administrators group.

Comment: You could try to get by name, clientContext.Load(groups, groupitems => groupitems.Include(groupitem => groupitem.Title,
        groupitem => groupitem.Description).Where(groupitem=> groupitem.Title == "Home Owners"));